# Any idea on how to make this text CSS animation responsive on small screens?

Tags: html, css, animation, text, responsiveness

I have a text slidein animation I am working with but the text does not stack up on small screens.  Instead it runs off the screen.  I'd like to have both sentences on the same line on large and extra large screens and it to stack on smaller screens.  So far I have it stacked on no matter the size, looks fine on medium and up, but the text runs off the screen on small screens.  Any tips on what I should be doing?

Screenshots:
[Full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pGr7.jpg)
[Small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSnXw.jpg)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #ccc 25%, #eee 40%, #ddd 55%);
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-top: 40vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.intro {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
}

.intro:first-of-type {
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
}

.intro~.intro {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
  white-space: normal;
}

.intro~.intro span {
  margin-left: -355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  white-space: normal;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 650px;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 650px;
  }
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="intro">Hello.</div>
  <div class="intro col-xs-12">
    <span>My name is Nate and I need this responsive</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Screenshot of current and desired behavior might be helpful

Comment: Oh yes, my fault.  Here you have screen shots of both full screen and small screen.  Thanks @Snappawapa .

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make a slidein from left look good with all the text on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with it a bit, I don't think you can get the effect you want by *just* defining your CSS animations just right.  Your best bet is to set different behavior for different screen widths, using `@media` rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 649px) {
    /* Rules for small screens */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    /* Rules for medium screens */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* Rules for large screens */
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  I'm giving it a go now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      html {
      font-size: 75%;
      }
    }
```

The font should looks good on smaller screens now. YOu can change the `min-width` and the responsive `font-size` value to whatever you think it would work best.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm playing around with it now.

Comment: Very personal stuff, but since I helped you a little bit, do you mind upvoting me? I'm trying to get to 50 reputations to be able to comment on other's post :(

Comment: I would totally but I don't have enough clout to upvote anyone yet I am afraid.  Unless there is a workaround?

Comment: I don't think there's one but it's ok, no worries